# Is There Ever A Good Situation NOT To Use A Primary Key?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, excel, database-design

Something I am currently doing involves converting several Excel sheets into MS SQL Server Databases. Most of these are completely unrelated to each other and don't to be linked. And at times, some of the fields may genuinely require NULL entries.

In anyone's experience developing databases, have you ever encountered a situation where it was OK to NOT use a primary key?

If not, what could I do in this situation?

Comment: A table without a unique key allows duplicate rows. From a fact-oriented point of view, what's the purpose of saying the same thing more than once?

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, every database table should have a primary key.  This is important when it comes to maintaining the data.  You can directly update and delete specific rows in the database.

Some databases maintain internal row ids that are visible to users.  That is definitely a possible alternative to a primary key, but I prefer having one explicitly defined even in those databases.

In addition, integer identity primary keys do the following:

- They identify the order of inserts into the table.
- They are a slight optimization on joins that use the key.
- They distinguish records that would otherwise be duplicates.
- They provide a "watermark" mechanism for keeping track of the last record updated.

Comment: If you are doing something 'on the fly' and importing data which doesn't have a primary key, then it's probably OK. But, at some stage, you may wish you had one and wish you'd put it in at the start. I've certainly had tables with no primary key for some applications but then, I'm naughty!

Comment: If I wanted to use row IDs as an alternate option, how could I do so?

Comment: That's the thing, these are used for Label printers. And the previous solution, excel sheets, were used willy nilly as pure data dumps

Comment: Normally I loved keeping to a nice structure. I'm just wondering what I can do when my hands are tied on the primary key

Comment: Not to disagree with your general advice, but I have one table in one database that has no primary key. The database is several terabytes, and the primary key would be backed by an index that takes up space for absolutely no benefit. The table does have an autogenerated identity that is functionally a PK; the constraint just isn't there. (The clustered index is on a non-unique time stamp.) This might fall under your "internal row ID" provision.

Comment: So what is a decent alternative to identify a row? This feels like a stupid question (and it kind of is), but like I said this circumstance is a little strange

Comment: @gonavy96, "If I wanted to use row IDs as an alternate option, how could I do so?" Switch database platform. I do not think SQL Server exposes row ids.

Comment: Gonavy, a simple option is to make a new field set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Answer (score 1):

The issue of primary keys is not directly related to whether other attributes in the table permit NULLs and also not directly related to whether the table needs to be linked to other relations (although primary keys are used in that kind of linking).

Rather, primary keys are all about establishing and maintaining *identity* of the objects represented by the rows in your table.  In any application in which you will need to know what real-world "thing" the row refers to, or in which one row with a set of values is not in every way identical and interchangeable with another row with the same values, then you will need a primary key.

You would not need a primary key in a situation when your table is used *only* to produce aggregate results in which a single source row has no meaning.  This does cover a wide range of reporting and analytic situations.  A primary key doesn't hurt, but is meaningless in this case.

You might want to specifically *avoid* a primary key in a situation in an analytic situation in which the data is an anonymized extract of a larger data set.  In this case, not having a primary key helps guarantee that the information *cannot* be traced back to the original source.

Comment: Knowing this, what is a good alternative to individually identify these rows?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have some way of uniquely identifying each row in your source data;  and you may **ever**  need to be able to manipulate or retrieve a specific row from your data, then you can create an artificial primary key.  E.g. 'Entry_ID'

The main issue I can see in your example, is if you import data and then need to modify it.

Say you import

```
Name | Age | Favourite Colour
-----------------------------
Anne | 23  |  red
John | 34  |  blue
John | 34  |  blue
```

If you want to delete one of the `John, 34, blue`'s , how would you do it?  Well, it's possible with some clunky code (I imagine you'll have more than 3 columns.)

```
Delete top (1) 
from testPK 
where name='john' 
and age=34 
and favouriteColour = 'blue';
```

But if you have this

```
Entry_ID | Name | Age | Favourite Colour
----------------------------------------
10001    |Anne | 23  |  red
10002    |John | 34  |  blue
10003    |John | 34  |  blue
```

Then it's simple as

```
Delete from Table where Entry_ID = 10003
```

Comment: That's a great idea, and one I considered for myself. The problem is, these datasets will need to be used on labels that don't have space for an extra junk id column

Comment: is there a way for me to hide this column?

Comment: from the result set of a "Select *"

Comment: Duh. Just hit me. Leave that column out of the select statement haha

Answer (score 0):

In my experience there are lots of situations you don't need to use PK. Especially if you are importing some data from external sources, you can import everything in a bulk to a staging architecture and than treat the data and distribution afterwards (ETL). That is better in terms of performance and deduplication, cleasing, etc.

Sometimes you could also use some dictionary tables with FREETEXT search, which also doesn't necessary require a PK.

That being said, in most cases your production table have a PK for many reasons: performance, organization, etc...

Comment: Thank you. Seriously informative stuff from everyone here. I'm fresh out of school so staying by the books is on my brain. This was such a weird instance for me when everything here is just large amounts of raw data that didn't need limits and restricitions

Answer (score 0):

In my early database development experience I often left off primary keys, particularly with data imported from elsewhere, like your Excel sheets.  And nothing terrible happened.  But in retrospect I was playing with fire and a lot of things *could* easily have gone wrong.

So I think the best answer to this question is to turn it on its head: Is there ever a situation where using a Primary Key would be a **bad** idea?  I can't think of a situation where a Primary Key would cause a problem.

As for converting Excel files, the approach I use is to straight import the Excel sheet as a table that exists just to store the data until I put it into a "real" table for use in the database.  I create the "real" table with a Primary Key `IDENTITY` field + all the fields from the Excel sheet and use `INSERT INTO` to transfer the data.  Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE real_table
    (
    Pkey int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY not null
    , Column_A varchar(255) null
    , Column_B varchar(255) null
    )

INSERT INTO real_table(
    Column_A
    , Column_B)
select
    Column_A
    , Column_B
from Excel_import_table
```